# Specify CMake generator unless explicitly passed as command argument by user

Tags: cmake

In all of the following, I'm using Windows, so `WIN32` is always defined in CMake.

I have a `CMakeLists.txt` file which does its job fine, and I'm using a `Preload.CMake` file to specify a bunch of stuff, including a certain generator depending on circumstances:

```
if( WIN32 )
    message( "Current generator: ${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" )           # For debugging purposes
    if( NOT COMMAND cl OR NOT COMMAND nmake )
        set( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "g++" )
        set( CMAKE_GENERATOR "MinGW Makefiles" CACHE STRING "" FORCE )
        set( CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM "make" )
        message( "MSVC compiler could not be found, attempting with g++ and MinGW makefiles." )
    endif(  )
endif(  )
```

This allows a Windows user with no Visual Studio to run `cmake ..` instead of a whole `cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"`.
It works pretty well, here is the output when `cmake ..` is run from an empty directory (no cache, no nothing):

```
Current generator:
MSVC compiler could not be found, attempting with g++ and MinGW makefiles.
Windows detected, forcing static libs.
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.2.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/SAYENS/Desktop/picross/build
```

The problem with this is when I want to specify a generator through the command line. Here is what happens when I run `cmake .. -G "MSYS Makefiles"` from a MSYS terminal (empty directory, no cache):

```
Current generator:
MSVC compiler could not be found, attempting with g++ and MinGW makefiles.
CMake Error: Error: generator : MSYS Makefiles
Does not match the generator used previously: MinGW Makefiles
Either remove the CMakeCache.txt file and CMakeFiles directory or choose a different binary directory.
```

*(There is no such file as CMakeCache.txt or a CMakeFiles directory, but explicitly specifying a generator in the command line, that is different from the one specified in Preload.CMake, seems to be enough of a source of confusion to print out this message.)*

I thought I'd be able to work around the issue by "catching" the value of the `-G` argument with `CMAKE_GENERATOR`, but it turns out I can't, as per the first output line `Current generator:`.

How can I work this out? I tried looking for a way to parse command line arguments, but found none that doesn't involve using a wrapper script, which I'd like to avoid resorting to.

Answer (score 2):

Set the generator name in the [environment variable CMAKE_GENERATOR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/envvar/CMAKE_GENERATOR.html). The documentation says:

> Specifies the CMake default generator to use when no generator is
>   supplied with -G. If the provided value doesn’t name a generator known
>   by CMake, the internal default is used. Either way the resulting
>   generator selection is stored in the CMAKE_GENERATOR variable.
>
> Some generators may be additionally configured using the environment
>   variables:
>
> ```
> CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM
> CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET
> CMAKE_GENERATOR_INSTANCE
> ```

Comment: That seems to be a good way to go about it, however one of my concerns here really is not to have the user issue a `set CMAKE_GENERATOR="MinGW Makefiles"` by themselves. I tried using `execute_process( COMMAND cmd /c "set CMAKE_GENERATOR=\"MinGW Makefiles\"" )` within my Preload.CMake file, but it has no effect since the command is invoked in a newly executed instance of cmd and is not persisted to the current cmd session; and that's about the only way to do such a thing (AFAIK). Maybe I'll resort to having a standalone script managing the whole thing after all. Thanks for your answer.